# jQuery: Count different children with same class in loop

Tags: jquery

Let's assume i have HTML like this:

```
<div class="somediv"></div> 
<div class="children child1">Text</div>
<div class="children child1">Text</div>
<div class="children child1">Text</div>
<div class="children child2">Text</div>
<div class="children child2">Text</div>
<div class="children child2">Text</div>
<div class="children child2">Text</div>
<div class="children child2">Text</div>
<div class="children child3">Text</div>
<div class="children child3">Text</div>
<div class="someotherdiv"></div> 

... child 4, child 5 etc. child n;
```

How can i create a jQuery loop, where i count how many .child1, .child2, .child3, ... exist?

*p.s.: function .length(); does not work for now, 
so maybe let's find an alternative to that. Furthermore there will be many other divs in DOM with multiple other classes, which should not be treated/affected here (performance).*

Comment: I would suppose that you only want to count those who also has the class of `children`?

Comment: we could, but its not necessary. i just wanted to show that also would have one other class in common - if we need that

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use jQuery for that actually: using plain JavaScript can easily get the job done. All you need is to use a selector that will apply to your elements of interest (in this case, I've ran with `div`, but you can use, for example, `.children` to narrow your selection down).

Once you've retrieved the HTMLCollection, you simply iterate through it. For every HTML element you encounter, you iterate through its [`classList` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and push them/increment their corresponding value in a dictionary:

```js
const classDictionary = {};
const els = document.querySelectorAll('div');

Array.from(els).forEach(el => {
  el.classList.forEach(className => {
    if (!(className in classDictionary)) {
      classDictionary[className] = 1;
    } else {
      classDictionary[className]++;
    }
  });
});

console.log(classDictionary);
```

```html
<div class="children child1">Text</div>
<div class="children child1">Text</div>
<div class="children child1">Text</div>
<div class="children child2">Text</div>
<div class="children child2">Text</div>
<div class="children child2">Text</div>
<div class="children child2">Text</div>
<div class="children child2">Text</div>
<div class="children child3">Text</div>
<div class="children child3">Text</div>
```

---

Of course, if you *really* have to use jQuery, that's also entirely possible:

```js
$(function() {
  const classDictionary = {};
  
  $('div').each(function() {
    this.classList.forEach(className => {
      if (!(className in classDictionary)) {
        classDictionary[className] = 1;
      } else {
        classDictionary[className]++;
      }
    });
  });

  console.log(classDictionary);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="children child1">Text</div>
<div class="children child1">Text</div>
<div class="children child1">Text</div>
<div class="children child2">Text</div>
<div class="children child2">Text</div>
<div class="children child2">Text</div>
<div class="children child2">Text</div>
<div class="children child2">Text</div>
<div class="children child3">Text</div>
<div class="children child3">Text</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that draft!
But shouldnt the counting result be "child1": 3, "child2": 5, "child3": 2 .. .and in total 10 children?

Comment: And how can i read this filled dictionary afterwards, when not knowing how many child1-n are inside?

Comment: @djmg My bad: the starting count should be `1` not `0`: too used to zero-based index :) to read the dictionary, you will need to iterate through the object keys, since you don't know what classes are available. `Object.keys(classDictionary)` should list all the classes that the method has found when iterating through your DOM.

Answer (score 0):

if you know n value already
this is the way to get it

```
n = 5; arr = [];
   for(i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        abc = ".children.child" + i ;
        console.log($(abc).length);
        arr[abc ] = $(abc).length;
   }
  console.log(arr);
```

Comment: .length() not working for me. A different solution is needed

Comment: you should use .length a property, it is not .length() a function